# In_array dont work with $term_id

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am making a code that grab a url part, take values and then set on list.

Problem is on list

```
if (in_array($term->term_id, $regions)) {
    $selected_region = 'selected';
}
else {
$selected_region = 'not';
}
```

This code does work, always return not.

```
if ($term->term_id == 2) {
$selected_region = 'varbut?';
}
```

This work.

$regions is variable and return this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "17" [1]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Where is the problem to use $term_id?

`$term_id` with var_dump returns `int(17) int(2)`

On other pages, single page with only one term is working and code is this:

```
    <?php 
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $postterms = wp_get_post_terms($id, 'destinations');   // get post terms
    $parentId = $postterms[0]->term_id;   // get parent term ID
    ?>
    <?php if (!in_array($parentId, $regions)): ?>
```

Why is not working on that selected function? int and string values?

Here is a full term get code:

```
$custom_terms = get_terms(array($taxonomies), $args);
foreach($custom_terms as $term){
    if (in_array($term->term_id, $regions)) {
        $selected_region = 'selected';
    }
    else {
        $selected_region = 'not';
    }
    if ($term->term_id == 2) {
        $selected_region = 'varbut?';
    }
    echo $selected_region;

    var_dump($term->term_id);

}
```

}

Comment: Your question title says `in_array`, but your code says `array_intersect`?

Comment: First of all `var_dump($term_id)` can't return `int(17) int(2)` It's **two** variables. Either `$term_id` is 17 or `$term_id` is 2. According to if clause it's `2`.

Comment: Var dump is set on foreach, like $term_id.

Comment: Could you add a full output from that bottom snippet of code? So we can see the value of `$selected_region` and `$term->term_id` after each iteration.

Comment: Also, try useing `in_array(strval($term->term_id), $regions)`. By default, `in_array` shouldn't use strict comparison...but it's worth trying in case wordpress has things configured differently somehow...

Answer (score 0):

It's like you said;

```
$regions : array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "17" [1]=> string(1) "2" } 
$term->term_id : int(2)
```

How about converting your $regions to ints?